# Can i move drive files with their ids?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup, google-drive-api

i have a doubt about Google Drive Files.

I have an account with several files that i save and access from a web app, every time i upload a file to GDrive, the service gives me an id which i use to download the file later on. The question is, **How can i make a backup of all my files without changing their ids?**

I can export my database with the ids... and i can make a copy of the files too, but if something happens, and i have to upload all the files over again, the ids would not be the same!!! so i will not have access to them...

Does anyone know how can i do this??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It can't be done. You will need to store a map of filenames to IDs somewhere, and update that map with the new IDs after a restore.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid for your comment, the bad news are that some of the files have the same name in the database! ( users.. :S ), however, i really appreciate your help. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reload a file in GDrive, it becomes a **new** file, also if its name is unchanged, so it is assigned a new id.

It's not clear where are you making a backup of the GDrive files:

- if you back them up on a local hd, you loose any link to the GDrive object. In this case, it is possible to use the path/file name as a unique key, when you want to rebuild the database.
- If you make a copy **in** GDrive, the copied files get a new id, but retain their "Description" (an attribute that you can edit manually or using a script. In this case, you can store in the description the original id, so you will be able to retrieve it when you restore the file, and update your database with the *restored* ids.

Comment: thanks Massimo, i was hoping to find a way around, but it seems there´s no such way... :S, thank you for the answer!

Comment: I was going to make the same suggestion as massimo. Once you accept that the Ids will change on a re-upload, it's really not that difficult to store the original ID in the description and use that to update the old stored Ids to the new ones.